# Mysql/ Grafana to calculate/display incremenet/ decrement of weight for the last hour/ day/ week/ month

Tags: python, mysql, grafana

I have a database containing values of weights. I am seeking some kind of mysql select/function what I can use in Grafana to calculate and display: increase/ decrease of weight in the time for the last hour, for the last day, for the last week and the last month.

Values are sent to the database each hour, so for each hour I have different weight. There can be increase but also decrease in the weight.

Example: 
ID    | weight  | timestamp 
 
6560  | 42.6    | 2021-09-02 22:00:42 
6559  | 42.3    | 2021-09-02 21:00:30 
6558  | 41.8    | 2021-09-02 20:00:15 
6557  | 41.5    | 2021-09-02 19:00:42 
.
.
.
6536  | 39.8    | 2021-09-01 22:00:51

A) last hour increase/ decrease of weight = 42.6 - 42.3 = 0.3 kg 
B) last day increase/ decrease of weight = value from 2021-09-02 22:00:42 - value from record 2021-09-01 22:00:51 = 42.6 - 39.8kg = 2.8 kg 
C) last week - similar but there can be used average function per day 
D) last month - similar but there can be used average function per week

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the gains for 1 hour, 1 day and 1 week for each record run this query:

```
SELECT now.*
, now.weight - hour_ago.weight AS gain_1_hour
, now.weight - day_ago.weight AS gain_1_day
, now.weight - week_ago.weight AS gain_1_week
FROM weights AS now
LEFT JOIN weights AS hour_ago ON hour_ago.ts >= DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 61 MINUTE) AND hour_ago.ts <= DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 59 MINUTE)
LEFT JOIN weights AS day_ago ON day_ago.ts >= DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 60 * 24 + 1  MINUTE) AND day_ago.ts <= DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 60 * 24 - 1 MINUTE)
LEFT JOIN weights AS week_ago ON week_ago.ts >= DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 7 * 60 * 24 + 1  MINUTE) AND week_ago.ts <= DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 7 * 60 * 24 - 1 MINUTE)
ORDER BY now.ID
;
```

The `ts` (timestamp) field must be indexed.

I recommend you that in your application to modify the input of timestamp values from `2021-09-02 22:00:42`, `2021-09-02 21:00:30` into `2021-09-02 22:00:00`, `2021-09-02 21:00:00`. This would improve performance and the above query would become:

```
SELECT now.*
, now.weight - hour_ago.weight AS gain_1_hour
, now.weight - day_ago.weight AS gain_1_day
, now.weight - week_ago.weight AS gain_1_week
FROM weights AS now
LEFT JOIN weights AS hour_ago ON hour_ago.ts = DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
LEFT JOIN weights AS day_ago ON day_ago.ts = DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
LEFT JOIN weights AS week_ago ON week_ago.ts = DATE_SUB(now.ts, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
ORDER BY now.ID
;
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions and code, that's what I have been looking for. Unfortunately I cannot change ts (reading_time) in application as it is current timestamp (type: timestamp, default: current_time). Do you have any idea how I can force my mysql server/ database to save current timestamp in the format: YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:00? It means that there will be seconds equal to "00" for each timestamp record. Is that possible somehow? Thank you.

Comment: Try to use a TRIGGER ... AFTER INSERT which updates the timestamp, something like `@timestamp = DATE_SUB(@timestamp, INTERVAL SECOND(@timestamp) SECOND)`